# Why do I need trailing comma in multiple assignment / unpacking?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

**CASE 1**
code in below works well

```
d, c, b, *a = 5, 4, 3, 1, 2
print(type(a), a)
print(type(b), b)
print(type(c), c)
print(type(d), d)
```

Results

```
   <class 'list'> [1, 2]
   <class 'int'> 3
   <class 'int'> 4
   <class 'int'> 5
```

**CASE 2**
But as soon as i remove d,c,b  and keep only *a then its ERROR;

```
 *a =  1, 2
print(type(a), a)

    *a =  1, 2
    ^
SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple
```

**CASE 3**
i have to put comma in last to make it work But in **CASE 1**  it worked as their *a was in last as well

```
*a, =  1, 2
print(type(a), a)
<class 'list'> [1, 2]
```

**My understanding is;**

***a  -- This itself mean that pack the right side of elements and create a list. why its looking for "," in last ?**

Comment: "starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple" means that the left side of the assignment must be a list or tuple.  You cannot have a starred identifier on the left side by itself.

Comment: Your title is irrelevant to your question. Please [edit] your title so it summarizes your question

Comment: `1, 2` is _already_ a tuple. To assign it to `a`, you just need `a = 1, 2`. To assign a list, do `a = [1, 2]`. The starred assignment is only useful when you want to unpack a collection, assigning some elements to some names, and the remaining elements to a single name

Comment: @PranavHosangadi . I edited Title.

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code/output.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) (Also I fixed your title.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky - Thanks to correct the Title. I removed the images and will takecare next time.

Answer (score 3):

`*a` is *not* looking for a list. It's looking for an arbitrary number of elements *inside* a list or a tuple. It then stores those elements in a list.

In an expression like `[a, *b] = [0, 1, 2, 3]`, There is a list unpacking, trying to *match two lists*, matching each nth element of a list to one corresponding element of the other. However if the nth element of the left hand side has a star, it will instead be able to match to *several* elements of the right hand side and it will store those elements as a list of a.

In `*a = [0, 1, 2, 3]`, a is trying to be matching multiple elements from... nothing ? There are no list patterns on the left hand side *a can feed from. If you want to match several elements of the right hand side, you must do a list or tuple unpacking:

```
[*a] = [0, 1, 2, 3] # left hand side is a list unpacking
(*a,) = [0, 1, 2, 3] # left hand side is a tuple unpacking
*a, = [0, 1, 2, 3] # left hand side is still a tuple unpacking
*a = [0, 1, 2, 3] # error, left hand size is not an unpacking as it doesn't have a list or tuple pattern so *a is meaningless
```

Comment: And remember that `(0)` is not a tuple, is a parenthesized expression equivalent to `0`. You must add a trailing comma to make it a unary tuple : `(0,)` or simply `0,`.

Comment: Thanks lot. ! Now it got better understanding.
*a, = [0, 1, 2, 3] # left hand side is still a tuple unpacking 
Left hand side *a, is tuple hence it could do unpaking of [0,1,2,3] in  variable a as list 

but *a = [0, 1, 2, 3] -- here left side it could not get anything wthether its  List OR Tuple Hence ERROR

Answer (score 0):

> `1, 2` is already a tuple. To assign it to a, you just need `a = 1, 2`. To assign a list, do `a = [1, 2]`.

correct, and agreed with above point. In case of `*a = 1, 2`, I would argue is misguided, being as the value `1, 2` is already a tuple. Thus, with this basically is saying, unpack the tuple `1, 2` due to `*` and get me all of it, the packed value that is, into a new unpacked tuple and I want the `1, 2`. Thus, double legwork for real no effect other than stylistic appeal I guess.

Interestingly, observe this:

```py
>>> _, *a = 1, 2, ...
>>> a
[2, Ellipsis]
>>> _, *a = 1,
>>> a
[]
```

Where the `_` is synonymous for, discard that *initial* unpacked value.

---

Btw: I guess you could also similarly expect `*a = 1` to unpack into list `[1]`, but that don't work neither. I guess you likely wanting `a = 1,` with the trailing comma at end - see that it's the same characters count too.

To get a **list**: You truthfully right. I didn't know about the `*a, = 1,` - but it's cool that it work "Like That ™️":

```py
>>> _, *_ = 1,
>>> _
[]
>>> a = 1,
>>> a
(1,)
>>> *_, = 1,
>>> _
[1]
```

Comment: Thanks ALL, 
I understood the use of  comma(,) after *a (i.e. *a,) 
and check this  good one as well. 
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007312.html